# Creating Web Application in Android

Tags: android

How to create an offline web application in Android using android.webkit package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following article talks about creating an offline web application in Android using android.webkit package.

http://www.linux-mag.com/id/7633/1/

Answer (score 2):

Using Phonegap framework should meet your purpose http://www.phonegap.com/